# Recommendations for creating a secure web app with WordPress, and google OAuth login

Tags: cms, wordpress, google-apps, authentication

I am creating a private web app for my company that allows users to view and manage sales material.

I would like to avoid creating the app entirely from scratch, so I felt that either web flow or WordPress would be a good option to build it in.

I have found plugins that let users log in with their email to the back end of WordPress but I want this to be all from the front end.

I am having trouble finding resources on how to restrict the entire front-end of the site with a single google login for anyone with the company domain in their gmail.

Any resources or ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I am still deciding the simplest way to accomplish this task.

Just recapping the requirements.

-Private web app which only allows users to access with google login.
-Front end created in WordPress.
-A easy to add CMS for users to add fields such as links or appointment dates.